# Angle between one vector and a list of vectors

Tags: functional-style, map

I have one vector `v1` and one list of vectors `v2`. I want to find the angle between them (see below):

```
v1 = {1, 0, 0};
v2 = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}; 

VectorAngle[v1, v2]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Look up `Map` and `Function` in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Szabolcs states you need to learn about `Map` and `Function`. These are very powerful and enable you to quickly calculate a list of values. Here I am using map. The `#` is a slot and the `&` makes a function.

```
v1 = {1, 0, 0};
v2 = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}};
VectorAngle[v1, #] & /@ v2
```

(*   `{π/2, 0}`  *)

For fun let's make 50 vectors then plot them

```
v2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];
Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ v2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are all their angles

```
ListPlot[VectorAngle[v1, #] & /@ v2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Have fun learning Mathematica.

Comment: Wow...Thanks a lot for your wonderful explanation!!